# Unable to upload ParseFile to Parse from Unity

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

So i've managed to create a user using the facebookutils, download data from facebook, including email & profile pic. I've then been able to map out the email and profile Pic (i think) to the parse user and parsefile respectively. I then try to upload all of this to parse, and fail. I was able to get the email updated when i commented out the pic code, so obviously the problem is with the image. Here are all the code snippets pertaining to the download, processing & upload of the image. The specific error I get at upload time is:

FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format

The documents are not particularly thorough, so I've derived the below by myself...but I suspect i'm doing something wrong... i've placed "comments" next to each line so my intention is clear of what i was attempting to do.

oh and i'm doing this in Unity, I hope someone can help

```
        Dictionary<string, string> url = new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"picture", "picture"}};

        FB.API("me?fields=picture.height(200)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, FetchProfilePic, url);

    JSONNode resultData = JSON.Parse (result.Text);   //here i receive the image data in JSON
    urlme = resultData ["picture"] ["data"] ["url"];  // here i'm just parsing it
     imageLink = new WWW(urlme);                      // here i'm just setting it as a url

    yield return imageLink;                           // this returns an object with the image


    byte [] profileData = imageLink.bytes;            // assigning the data of the object to a byte[] object
    ParseFile profilePicFile = new ParseFile( "profilePic.jpg", profileData);   // creating a parsefile object & inserting the byte object

    Task saveProfilePic = profilePicFile.SaveAsync(); // sending the parsefile to parse
    yield return saveProfilePic;                      // waiting for the operation to complete

    user["Profile_Pic"] = profilePicFile;           // assigning the parsefile to the user with a key (this key is a new column)
    Task updateUser = user.SaveAsync();             // sending the updated user to parse
```

Comment: Did you check WWW.error? From what I recall FB.API only returns the picture I'd, and you need to build the appropriate URL. Either way, check WWW request's error log as well as WWW.result.

Comment: I'll check, but the picture loads just fine. Prior to sending it to parse, I pull the  www's texture and assign it to a profile pic sprite, which works... and I use Yield Returns prior to the parse push to ensure it doesnt run till its properly build

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
byte [] profileData = imageLink.bytes;
```

by

```
if(imageLink.error == null)
{
    Texture2D profilePic = imageLink.texture;
    if(profilePic != null)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = profilePic.EncodeToPNG();
        // write code for creating parse file from bytes here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but i'm still getting hte same error FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format.


 `  byte [] bytes = imageLink.texture.EncodeToPNG();
    profilePicFile = new ParseFile( "profilePic.png", bytes);
    Task     saveProfilePic = profilePicFile.SaveAsync();`

Comment: also i cant seem to get code to appear in comments, if someone could help with that...